# chain decomposition on partial order set

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

I am trying to do exercise in this [book](https://books.google.com.tw/books/about/Combinatorics_of_Finite_Sets.html?id=RjDd4RaqrIwC&redir_esc=y) (page 54, number 3.11). The question :

Find orthogonal chain decomposition as required in the proof of theorem from Shearer & Kleitman for $n=3$ and $n=4$.

> Theorem (Shearer and Kleitman 1979)
>
> If $n \geq 2$, there exist two orthogonal chain decompositions of the poset of subsets of an $n$-set into $\binom {n}{[n/2]}$ chains.

Some definitions :
Suppose we can find two chain decompositions of $P$ (we define $P$ as partial order set) into $m$ chains with the property that no pair elements of $P$ in the same chain in one of the decompositions lies in the same chain in the second decomposition (such a pair of chain decompositions are said to be orthogonal).

I know that for $n=3$, chain decomposition will be :

$\emptyset \subset \{1\} \subset \{12\} \subset \{123\}$

$\{2\} \subset \{23\}$

$\{3\} \subset \{13\}$

For $n=4$, it has 6 chain decompoitions. Then how to find orthogonal chain decomposition for $n=3$ and $n=4$ ?

Answer (score 1):

(At long last getting this off the unanswered list.)

In a chain decomposition for $n=3$ that is orthogonal to yours, $\varnothing$, $\{1\}$, $\{1,2\}$, and $\{1,2,3\}$ must all go into different chains, so the decomposition must have (at least) four chains. The remaining four subsets of $\{1,2,3\}$ are $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$, $\{1,3\}$, and $\{2,3\}$, and we can begin by trying to add one of them to each of the four chains that we’ve started.

The only one that can be added to $\{1\}$ is $\{1,3\}$, giving us a chain $\{1\}\subset\{1,3\}$, and the only one that can be added to $\{1,2\}$ is $\{2\}$, giving us a chain $\{2\}\subset\{1,2\}$. Each of $\{3\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ can be added to either of the remaining chains, so we get the chain decompositions

$$\begin{align*}
\varnothing&\subset\{3\}\\
\{1\}&\subset\{1,3\}\\
\{2\}&\subset\{1,2\}\\
\{2,3\}&\subset\{1,2,3\}
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
\varnothing&\subset\{2,3\}\\
\{1\}&\subset\{1,3\}\\
\{2\}&\subset\{1,2\}\\
\{3\}&\subset\{1,2,3\}\,.
\end{align*}$$

For that matter, we could add both $\{3\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ to either of the remaining chains to get the chain decompositions

$$\begin{align*}
&\varnothing\subset\{3\}\subset\{2,3\}\\
&\{1\}\subset\{1,3\}\\
&\{2\}\subset\{1,2\}\\
&\{1,2,3\}
\end{align*}$$

and

$$\begin{align*}
&\varnothing\\
&\{1\}\subset\{1,3\}\\
&\{2\}\subset\{1,2\}\\
&\{3\}\subset\{2,3\}\subset\{1,2,3\}\,.
\end{align*}$$

Each of these is easily seen to be orthogonal to yours.

For $n=4$ we can start with the symmetric chain decomposition of **Example** $\mathbf{3.1.1}$:

$$\begin{align*}
&\{3,4\}\\
&\{2,4\}\\
&\{4\}\subset\{1,4\}\subset\{1,2,4\}\\
&\{3\}\subset\{1,3\}\subset\{1,3,4\}\\
&\{2\}\subset\{2,3\}\subset\{2,3,4\}\\
&\varnothing\subset\{1\}\subset\{1,2\}\subset\{1,2,3\}\subset\{1,2,3,4\}\,.
\end{align*}\tag{1}$$

Now we can apply the algorithm in the proof of **Theorem** $\mathbf{3.4.6}$. We first replace each set by its relative complement in $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to get

$$\begin{align*}
&\{1,2\}\\
&\{1,3\}\\
&\{3\}\subset\{2,3\}\subset\{1,2,3\}\\
&\{2\}\subset\{2,4\}\subset\{1,2,4\}\\
&\{1\}\subset\{1,4\}\subset\{1,3,4\}\\
&\varnothing\subset\{4\}\subset\{3,4\}\subset\{2,3,4\}\subset\{1,2,3,4\}\,.
\end{align*}$$

This is almost orthogonal to $(1)$: the only problem is that $\varnothing$ and $\{1,2,3,4\}$ are in the same chain. Following the algorithm in the proof, we simply move $\varnothing$ to any chain that does not contain any of the sets $\{1\}$, $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$, and $\{1,2,3,4\}$, i.e., to either the second or the fourth chain. Moving it to the second chain gives us the decomposition

$$\begin{align*}
&\{1,2\}\\
&\varnothing\subset\{1,3\}\\
&\{3\}\subset\{2,3\}\subset\{1,2,3\}\\
&\{2\}\subset\{2,4\}\subset\{1,2,4\}\\
&\{1\}\subset\{1,4\}\subset\{1,3,4\}\\
&\{4\}\subset\{3,4\}\subset\{2,3,4\}\subset\{1,2,3,4\}\,,
\end{align*}$$

which is indeed orthogonal to $(1)$.